# MqttDefaultFilePersistence paho - How to read a persist file in client application?

Tags: java, android, mqtt

http://blog.csdn.net/kuailebeihun_/article/details/25245023

I do this tutorial in eclipse kepler and everything is ok.

Now I'm trying put         String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
and       final  MqttDefaultFilePersistence dataStore = new MqttDefaultFilePersiste(tmpDir); in this project
and in the server project (i.e.: the server project publish msg(s) to topic "xxx/yyy", with qos = 2)

My questions is: In the first time when I start a java project (in eclipse) , I need read latest post of the topic "xxx/yyy" relative to dataStore file persist.

How to do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to read the persistence file? Messages will only be stored there until delivery has been confirmed (and then only on the publishing side), so assuming a good network connection the file should be effectively empty all the time.

If you just want to always have last published message on a given topic available to a subscribing client then publish it with the retained bit set to true. This means that when the client connects and subscribes to that topic the last message will be delivered.